# delegate internal question

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering if an event or multicast delegate in C# contains an internal list to hold all method, anyone knows it?

Comment: Do you mean event? Delegate is reference to only one method.

Comment: @Euphoric: An event is simply a pair of two methods...

Comment: @Lambert: No, event declaration allows add or remove many handlers within specific delagate. And it is wrong to say event is method.

Comment: @Euphoric: You're allowed to have events whose add/remove handlers don't do *anything* at all... they're completely a separate concept from delegates, it's just that they're used with delegates often.

Comment: "An event is simply a pair of two methods"

Wat

Comment: @Lambert: Yes, that is true. But events are so tightly tied to delegates it can cause confusion for beginer users. I dont know how to put "delegate" and "all methods" together so it makes sense.

Comment: @Euphoric: It's true that it might cause confusion, but saying that "Delegate is reference to only one method" and hence asking whether the OP meant "event" instead just misleads the OP even more, since his question was completely correct and clear, and didn't really give any hints that the OP might be a beginner.

Comment: @Martin: Just type in `event EventHandler MyEvent { add { } remove { } }` in C# and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Lambert: Now you are talking about event, not simple delagate. It seems confusion I was talking about is about you. If you remove the "event" part, then you can only get;set; single delegate reference.

Comment: @Euphoric: I was trying to show @Martin that events are unrelated to delegates; I'm not confused at all. I think you're confused because you think a "single delegate" means a "single method", but check my post; that's not the case.

Comment: Events are INSTANCES of delegates. The 'event' keyword is simply a modifier on an event instance, in the same way 'const' and 'readonly' are modifiers on class instances. An event is certainly not 'a pair of methods'.

Comment: The word `event` is *exactly* like the word `property` -- it represents a group of (often) two methods, and of course, in the IL code, it's represented by an event instance and it marks the methods as special names... but that's getting too ahead of the point. The point is that an event has *no* inherent relation to delegates whatsoever, just like how `property` is **not** inherently related to instance fields, even though properties frequently wrap field accesses.

Comment: @Martin: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx for more on the difference between an event and a delegate. An event certainly *is* a pair of methods (possibly even a trio or more, but commonly a pair). That's why EventInfo has GetAddMethod and GetRemoveMethod (as well as others).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [MulticastDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx):

> A MulticastDelegate has a linked list of delegates, called an invocation list, consisting of one or more elements. When a multicast delegate is invoked, the delegates in the invocation list are called synchronously in the order in which they appear. If an error occurs during execution of the list then an exception is thrown.

Update 1:

To prevent confusion: in .NET, *all* `Delegate`s inherit from `MulticastDelegate`, and so *all* delegates can hold multiple elements in their invocation list.

Update 2:

See Jon Skeet's post for a fun fact. :)

Comment: It may be worth explicitly stating (in this answer rather than just in other comments) that in .NET *all* delegate types derive from MulticastDelegate.

Comment: @Jon: Great idea, thank you for the suggestion! I'll do that right now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Although the documentation for `MulticastDelegate` *claims* that it stores a linked list for all the method invocations, I believe it *actually* uses an array. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action<string> a = x => Console.WriteLine("First " + x);
        Action<string> b = y => Console.WriteLine("Second " + y);

        Action<string> c = a + b;

        foreach (var field in typeof(MulticastDelegate).GetFields
                 (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            object value = field.GetValue(c);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", field.Name, value);
            if (value != null && value.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                foreach (var subvalue in (IEnumerable)value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  - " + subvalue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
_invocationList: System.Object[]
  - System.Action`1[System.String]
  - System.Action`1[System.String]
_invocationCount: 2
_target: System.Action`1[System.String]
_methodBase:
_methodPtr: 2662852
_methodPtrAux: 1526207940
```

As you can tell, `_invocationList` is an array containing the two individual actions. (I believe the first of those actions will have the same _methodPtr, i.e. a multicast delegate knows the first method to invoke "natively" but uses the invocation list for the rest.)

Comment: I definitely didn't see this one coming... looking forward to the sample!

Comment: +1 Yup, seems like you're right; a simple disassembly with Reflector shows `object[] objArray = this._invocationList as object[];` as the first statement of `MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList()`.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate contains a reference to a method. It does not contain the method itself. A regular delegate only references one method.

I strongly suspect you are asking something else but have not articulated it fully. Perhaps you can expand and clarify your question a bit.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "regular delegate". *All* .NET delegates are `MulticastDelegate` s, which you can verify, for example, with just calling `GetType().BaseType.Name` with any delegate instance.

Comment: MulticastDelegate inherits from Delegate. Are you saying there's no way to use Delegate from .NET?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying -- you simply *can't* have a delegate that doesn't inherit from `MulticastDelegate`, and hence you *can't* have any delegate that's only capable of referring to a single method (since you said "A regular delegate only references one method."). At least, no way that I've figured out so far... if you have an example please share it!! :)